# Why does lighting on the object changes when I import it as Unity Package from my old project to new one?

Tags: unity, lighting

Here is the original lighting ( Unity 2021.1)
[image]

And Here is the same setup imported in a new project ( Unity 2021.1):
[image]

As you can see importing this package in new Unity project makes it a lot lighter and I am not sure why. There aren't any additional lights int the scene and setting are the same. I use standard rendering pipeline.

For the prefab it is just a model with 3 directional lights.

Comment: The new version looks lighter to me, not darker, unless the screenshots are reversed. Can you walk us through the steps to create a Minimal Complete Verifiable Example of the problem? Once we can reproduce the issue, we can test potential causes/fixes to be sure we've found the right one.

Comment: Yeah I meant lighter sorry. I didn't did anything special I made a Unity package of the prefab and just imported it to a new project. The difference between the projects is the version. This is the prefab view.

Comment: I'm not asking you to repeat what you already stated in your question. I'm asking you to find a set of steps that reliably reproduces this issue, and give us those exact steps, so we can follow them and see exactly what you're seeing, then test potential fixes.

Comment: I mean there isn't anything specific I didn't already said. I created a model put 3 directional lights on it. Created a prefab from that model and than created a Unity package from that prefab. I than imported that package in a new project and got different lighting. You can try it with some random model it doesn't have to  be anything special.

Comment: So walk us through the steps to create **the specific** model and prefab and lights that demonstrate the issue. Try making a new project and following exactly the steps you give us, to be sure they reproduce the problem.

Comment: To be hones I am not sure how to reproduce it correctly because when I try it with ordinary cube I don't have a problem.

Comment: That indicates that there's something special about the model you're using that causes the problem, and we don't have that documented here. So you'll need to do some experiments, making and importing models that are like that one in certain respects, to test which aspects affect the imported result. We can't do that for you, since we don't have the model that causes the problem or the steps to produce our own (yet).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out; it was something I completely overlooked. The original scene was created with Default Behavior Mode set to 2D and my new scene is created with Default Behavior set to 3D, so that was causing a lighting difference and I wasn't aware of this.

I just removed the skybox material from the Lighting window -> Enviroment.

Comment: The relevant difference there is that there would be an extra light in your scene hierarchy. Showing the scene hierarchy as part of your question would have allowed users to help you diagnose this.

Comment: Not really I removed the default light. The difference is that in Lighting window in environment there is a skybox material on 3d but not on 2d.

Comment: Ah, then showing your lighting settings instead of asserting they were the same would also have helped.

Comment: To be honest didn't think of them.

Comment: This is why we ask that questions about debugging an issue in your game include the steps to reproduce a Minimal Complete Verifiable Example. The process of preparing such an example forces you to ensure you've covered every relevant degree of freedom that could contribute to the issue.